# What's the differences between !$pristine vs $dirty in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation

Recently I read some tutorial about angularJS form validation, like this:

```
<p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && !userForm.email.$pristine"></p>
```

but I think `!$pristine` and `$dirty` are equal, so can I use the below one instead?

```
<p ng-show="userForm.email.$invalid && userForm.email.$dirty"></p>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use either, like you said they're both booleans so `!$pristine === $dirty`. I prefer the bottom one as well, I'd rather test for `$dirty`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think there is a slight difference between these two attributes, which depends on your use case.

**$setDirty();**
Sets the form to a dirty state.
This method can be called to add the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to a dirty state (ng-dirty class). This method will also propagate to parent forms.

**$setPristine();**
Sets the form to its pristine state.
This method can be called to remove the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to its pristine state (ng-pristine class). This method will also propagate to all the controls contained in this form.
Setting a form back to a pristine state is often useful when we want to 'reuse' a form after saving or resetting it.

So, you can use both $pristine and $dirty in a different way. Though, you can check the document as mentioned by 'macrog' in the below post.

Answer (score 6):

$pristine
boolean 
True - if user has not interacted with the form yet.

$dirty
boolean 
True - if user has already interacted with the form.

you can read all [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: Basically ng-dirty and ng-pristine are like two sides of the same story.

Answer (score 1):

$pristine: It will be TRUE, if the user has not interacted with the form yet

$dirty: It will be TRUE, if the user has already interacted with the form.

in essence !$pristine === $dirty

but **you can use their respected css classes** if you use them both.

In accordance with these AngularJS also provides corresponding CSS classes for them. We can use them for validation purpose.

```
ng-pristine
ng-dirty
```

Usage:

In Form: `myForm.$dirty`

For Field: `myForm.fieldName.$dirty`

In CSS:

```
.ng-dirty{
 background-color: yellow;
}
```